# Improving performance of a SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

Anyway to improve the performance of below sql query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   PART
WHERE  (
              Lower(sos) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     Lower(prt) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     Lower(cls) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     Lower(typ) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     Lower(ven) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     Lower(ofc) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     Lower(sear) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     Lower(des) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     EXISTS
              (
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM   partdescription
                     WHERE  pd_prt = prt
                     AND    pd_sta = 'A'
                     AND    pd_des1 LIKE '%tool%'
                     AND    pd_co = '01'
                     AND    pd_div = '01'
                     AND    pd_br = '01')
       OR     Lower(bin) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'
       OR     EXISTS
              (
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM   partbin 
                     WHERE  pb_prt = prt
                     AND    pd_co = '01'
                     AND    pd_div = '01'
                     AND    pd_br = '01'
                     AND    lower(pb_bin) LIKE '%tool%' ESCAPE '!'))
AND    co = '01'
AND    div = '01'
```

It's taking almost 40 to 45 sec to get the count.

part table has around 5 million rec, partDescription has 1.2 million rec, partBin has 30k rec

This is my first query where I am trying to optimise. When I checked with Explain, I see no index is getting applied , I think it's because of like '%%' search.

I tried using left outer join but I am getting duplicate values.

Thanks.

Comment: Which one is it? SQL Server or DB2? Those are two very different animals.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.  I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Whatever engine you are using, can you add the execution plan to your question?

Comment: The query is using LOWER() on multiple columns, which in Db2 will likely prevent usage of any applicable index, unless function-based-indexes are used.

Comment: There's a missing `WHERE` in the last subquery. How does this even run?

Comment: Actually, the where is missing from both `exists` subqueries.

Comment: Also, `column LIKE '%tool%'` as a search predicate is difficult on any database engine. It can't be optimized with standard B-tree indexing and will usually drive the optimizer to do table scans. If you really need to scan for a fragment of text in a huge table, you may need to consider full-text indexing, which gets us back to what platform are you on, and can you provide more details, as requested above?

Comment: @TheImpaler I am using DB2. Sorry for the mistake earlier.

Comment: Without more details, I might go crazy and suggest you create a boolean bit column called `tool`, and then use a trigger to check the dependent column values and set its value. Because then you could index that value because it's just a bit. And then a script to set its value initially. But I wouldn't do that, because that would be crazy.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to get execution plan. Currently, I am using System i navigator where we have a option for visual explain that's where I see if indexes are being used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The purpose of the above query is, we have a main search field when a user enter's any keyword there it has to search across all columns and retrieve all rows which has that specific keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is every search looks at **ALL** the text in **ALL** those fields in **ALL** of the rows, *without any possibility of using an index* (leading wild-card characters break index use). Yes, that's gonna be crazy-slow.

If you're not able to use something more purpose-built for this kind of search (Elastic?), and you want this to be faster, then I suggest adding a single [generated column](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020109.html) that concatenates the text from all of those fields into a single place. Then you can add a [Full-Text Index](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/databases/tutorials/dm-0810shettar/) on that new computed column and change the query to use a single [`CONTAINS()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ts.doc/doc/t_searchingwiththetextindex.html) search for just the one column. This will reduce/simplify the SQL, while **greatly** improving search performance.

Note this will make all your other data changes a little slower, because every update will need to update the column, and then update the index, which you have to do manually (perhaps in a trigger). But at least now you're spreading out this load more naturally over the entire application, instead of just at search time.

All of this still leaves the `EXISTS()` operations in place. You can optimize those by doing a similar change for the other tables or using a trigger to include data from those tables in the search column. Or perhaps setting up the main table to use a full-text index will help enough to make that unnecessary.